# Function not found even though I have the packages installed

Tags: r

I am trying to use the function rpareto. I have download both the actuar and the VGAM package for my code. My instructor says to use the rpareto from the VGAM package because it works better. However, every time I try to compile the code it gives me an error saying that the function cannot be found.

I have tried to update the app, moved the necessary folders to the working directory and I have redownloaded both packages.

Comment: Have you run `library(VGAM)` first to load the package into the environment?

Comment: Have you loaded the package in your R session with `library(VGAM)`? Packages can be installed on disk but not loaded.

Comment: please show actual error you got. So that we can help you.